# Is there an option to enable recurring payments in iPhone framework of PayPal?

Tags: iphone, paypal, recurring-billing

I am creating an iPhone app, Where I need to use PayPal framework for billing the user for purchasing some kind of service. But I need the bill the user on monthly basis. Is there any option to enable recurring payment option in the framework?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use PayPal, you'll likely have to roll your own solution using PayPal's APIs and a UIWebView and HTML/Javascript/etc...

The [PayPal Developer Network docs](https://www.paypal.com/pdn-recurring) has lots of information, including code examples.

You'll likely have a better time using Apple's own StoreKit API, which includes support for recurring subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend to use In-App Purchase because your app would be rejected if you're using something other than In-App Purchases!**

Since *The Daily* Apple doesn't want to let user buy additional content without using iTunes (In-App Purchase).
I know here are many German News having problems with this, because they are only give the content if buy them on it's website.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in native in app payment from a iPhone App or Android App, there is no direct recurring payment option. But we have a method of payment called Preapproval payment by which we can achieve the same goal.

For More informatiomn:

https://www.x.com/message/196767#196767

https://www.x.com/message/196766#196766